# jQuery accordion with additional div to be toggled

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion

I am trying to build a simple jQuery accordion but on page load the accordion is 50% of the page width, and there is content in the other 50%. When the accordion is opened, the content is to disappear (slide out using `hide('slow');` or `slideToggle('slow');` ) and the accordion is to become 100%. More than one section can expand at any one time but the content is not to come back in to view until all sections are closed.

What I have at the moment works perfectly on first click, content goes and accordion opens and expands, closing the same section also works where it closes and content returns, but if I open one then open another the content returns and the accordion opens the second section but goes back to 50%.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-half left accord-left">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="section"><!-- first section -->
                <div class="title">
                    <h3>Clickable title 1</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="accord-text content-block" style="display: none;">
                    This is section text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section"><!-- second section -->
                <div class="title">
                    <h3>Clickable title 1</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="accord-text content-block" style="display: none;">
                    This is section text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-half right accord-right content-block">
        This is the content to be removed when the accordion is open
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    jQuery('.accord-text').hide();
    jQuery('.section').click(function(){
        var secclick = jQuery(this);
        if(jQuery('.accord-text:visible').length) {
            jQuery('.accord-right').show('slow', function(){
                jQuery('.accord-left').addClass('col-half');
                jQuery('.accord-left').removeClass('col-full');
                jQuery('.accord-text',secclick).toggle("slow");
                jQuery('.title',secclick).toggleClass('open');
            });
        } else {
            jQuery('.accord-right').hide('slow', function(){
                jQuery('.accord-left').removeClass('col-half');
                jQuery('.accord-left').addClass('col-full');
                jQuery('.accord-text',secclick).toggle("slow");
                jQuery('.title',secclick).toggleClass('open');
            });
        }
    });
```

I think what it needs to do is check if it is the open section that's clicked or not, if so then close the section and show the right column, but if not then open the new section and keep the right column hidden, i'm not sure how that would be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have amended the jQuery so when a section is clicked, it will hide/keep hidden the right column, widen/keep left at 100% and toggle the accordion open/closed, then after 1250ms (because of the slow effect) it will check whether the accordion is open or not by checking the visibility of the text sections, if they're all closed then it will narrow the accordion back to 50% and slide the right column back in.

```
    jQuery('.accord-text').hide();
    jQuery('.section').click(function(){
        var secclick = jQuery(this);
        jQuery('.accord-right').hide();
        jQuery('.accord-left').addClass('col-full');
        jQuery('.accord-left').removeClass('col-half');
        jQuery('.title',this).toggleClass('open');
        jQuery('.accord-text',this).toggle("slow");
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(jQuery('.accord-text:visible').length) {
            } else {
                jQuery('.accord-left').removeClass('col-full');
                jQuery('.accord-left').addClass('col-half');
                jQuery('.accord-right').slideDown('slow');
            }
        },1250);            
    });
```